# How to box and unbox a struct with type safety

Tags: c#, struct, thread-safety, type-safety, boxing

There is [a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1) in the .NET platform that I would like to use as state for my class. It is important that the struct is built-in, so I can't change it. Lets say that this built-in struct is the `ImmutableStruct` below.

```
struct ImmutableStruct
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public ImmutableStruct(string value) { Value = value; }
}
```

My class is required to be thread-safe, so the state must be declared [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Of course there are other ways to achieve thread-safety, but lets say that a `volatile` field has been chosen as the best option for the specific case. So I code my class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private volatile ImmutableStruct _state = new ImmutableStruct("SomeString");
    // Error CS0677
    // 'MyClass._state': a volatile field cannot be of the type 'ImmutableStruct'

    public ImmutableStruct State => _state;

    /* Method that mutates the _state is omitted */
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler does not allow a `volatile` struct field. So I decide to use [boxing and unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing):

```
class MyClass
{
    private volatile object _state = new ImmutableStruct("SomeString");

    public ImmutableStruct State => (ImmutableStruct)_state;

    /* Method that mutates the _state reference is omitted */
}
```

This works, but casting from objects causes me anxiety, because the program becomes exposed to possible run-time errors. I would like a type-safe solution, with the compiler ensuring the correctness of the program at compile-time. So my question is: Is there any way to box and unbox a struct with type safety?

Btw there is a related question about marking structs as `volatile`: [Volatile for structs and collections of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925889/volatile-for-structs-and-collections-of-structs). My question defers in that it focuses specifically to the type-safety of the boxing/unboxing operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating generic wrapper like this:

```
public  class ReadonlyStructWrapper<T> where T: struct 
    {
        public T Value { get; }
        public ReadonlyStructWrapper(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `class StrongBox<T>`, doing essentially the same as described in Guru's answer, but available out of the box since ever (.NET Framework 3.5).

See also:

- [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1) at learn.microsoft.com
- [What's the purpose of StrongBox?](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/47774) at GitHub > dotnet/runtime, with more usage examples